# QMessageBox to block parent while calculation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I want to use `QMessageBox` to block its parent `QDialog`, while doing calculation.  I came upon something like that, but this does not work.

```
msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
msgBox.setWindowTitle('Working ....')
msgBox.setText("Working, please wait ...")
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoButton)
msgBox.exec_()

(doing some time consuming work)

msgBox.close()
```

What is wrong, how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute the time-consuming task in another thread and signal through a signal that the task is finished executing. To close the QMessageBox you must use the accept() method:

```py
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def execute(self, func, args):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, args=(func, args,), daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self, func, args):
        self.started.emit()
        func(*args)
        self.finished.emit()


def consuming_work(arg1, arg2):
    import time

    print(arg1, arg2)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("finish")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Working ....")
    msgBox.setText("Working, please wait ...")
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoButton)
    worker = Worker(msgBox)
    worker.finished.connect(msgBox.accept)
    worker.execute(consuming_work, ["Stack", "Overflow"])
    msgBox.exec_()
```

**Update:**

```py
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class WorkerMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.finished.connect(self.accept)

    def execute(self, func, args):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, args=(func, args,), daemon=True).start()
        return self.exec_()

    def _execute(self, func, args):
        self.started.emit()
        func(*args)
        self.finished.emit()


def consuming_work(arg1, arg2):
    import time

    print(arg1, arg2)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("finish")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    msgBox = WorkerMessageBox()
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Working ....")
    msgBox.setText("Working, please wait ...")
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoButton)

    msgBox.execute(consuming_work, ["Stack", "Overflow"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Would it be possible to define new class based on QMessageBox instead of a generic class?  I think this would be easier to use, i.e. Worker.setText(...), Worker.setWindowsTitle(...)...

Comment: @Pygmalion Yes, it is possible, I think that in general this should be part of your work but this time I will only show you how it could be done. Check my update.

Comment: I did almost exactly as you, except i put `exec_` on the wrong place.  But even your version does not work, I get `AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'`.  I guess something's wrong with my implementation.

Comment: @Pygmalion I just tested my code in Linux with PtQt5 5.14.1 and it works correctly, I recommend you copy my code without modifying it

Comment: I found error.  Just typing one command on wrong place, and it does not work.  I was close, but I couldn't have done it myself, probably.

Comment: As far as accepting answers is concerned, I accept the best answer a week after asking the question, if at least one answers it properly.  That was a recommendation from StackOverflow.  Your answer obviously qualify.